# executor tab /job tasks issue

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

here is my spark job executor tab on spark UI, not sure why there are so many tasks on one executor only, can anybody explain please.

[image]

Also, in the below picture why are there so many differences in the number of tasks created 17/17,20/20 etc, I can use proper number of cores if I know how many same number of tasks are being created 
[image]
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I guess because Spark realize 1 of your nodes is closest than other so the closest executor will do all the works.

So what you gonna try is try to increase `spark.locality.wait` to 10 or 15 because default is 3s.
But need to confirm by see something like that?
[image]

But it's not the best way to do. You need to move your datasource to closer with your executor because the cost of network transfer is expensive.

Ref:http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling